# Why is my JFrame blank in my breakout game?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm new at java and need some help with my breakout game. My `JFrame` is just blank and i don't know how to fix it?

So I have a ball class, paddle class, canvas class and a brick class as well as a main class. In my canvas class I set all functions the ball, paddle and bricks has etc. In brick class I draw the bricks. And in my main I do the `JFrame` but it's blank

Main class :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Canvas c = new Canvas();

        frame.add(c);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I expect the `JFrame` to show the game instead of just blank window

```
package breakout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


import breakout.Bricks.Type;

public class Canvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
        public static final int WIDTH = 720;

        private int horizontalCount;
        private BufferedImage image;
        private Graphics2D bufferedGraphics;
        private Timer time;
        private static final Font endFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20);
        private static final Font scoreFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 15);

        private Paddle player;
        private Ball ball;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Bricks>> bricks;


    public Canvas() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        bufferedGraphics = image.createGraphics();
        time = new Timer (15, this);
        player = new Paddle((WIDTH/2)-(Paddle.PADDLE_WIDTH/2));
        ball = new Ball (((player.getX() + (Paddle.PADDLE_WIDTH / 2 )) - (Ball.DIAMETER / 2)), (Paddle.Y_POS - (Ball.DIAMETER + 10 )), -5, -5);

        bricks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Bricks>>();
        horizontalCount = WIDTH / Bricks.BRICK_WIDTH;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            ArrayList<Bricks> temp = new ArrayList<Bricks>();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Type rowColor = null;
            switch(i) {
            case 0 :
            case 2:
                rowColor = Type.LOW;
                break;
            case 1 :
            case 3 :
            case 5 :
                rowColor = Type.MEDIUM;
                break;
            case 4 :
            case 6 :
                rowColor = Type.HIGH;
                break;
            case 7 :
                default :
                    rowColor = Type.ULTRA;
                    break;

            }
            for(int j = 0; j < horizontalCount; ++j) {
                Bricks tempBrick = new Bricks();
                temp.add(tempBrick);
            }
            bricks.add(temp);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            addMouseListener(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            requestFocus();

        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        checkCollisions();
        ball.Move();
        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.size(); ++i) {
            ArrayList<Bricks> al = bricks.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < al.size(); ++j) {
                Bricks b = al.get(j);
                if(b.dead()) {
                    al.remove(b);

                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private void checkCollisions() {
        if(player.hitPaddle(ball)) {
            ball.setDY(ball.getDY() * -1);
            return;
        }
        if(ball.getX() >= (WIDTH - Ball.DIAMETER) || ball.getX() <= 0) {
            ball.setDX(ball.getDX() * -1);
        }
        if(ball.getY() > (Paddle.Y_POS + Paddle.PADDLE_HEIGHT + 10)) {
            resetBall();
        }
        if(ball.getY() <= 0) {
            ball.setDY(ball.getDY() * -1);
        }
        int brickRowActive = 0;
        for(ArrayList<Bricks> alb : bricks) {
            if(alb.size() == horizontalCount) {
                ++brickRowActive;
            }
        }

        for(int i = (brickRowActive==0) ? 0 : (brickRowActive - 1); i < bricks.size(); ++i) {
            for(Bricks b : bricks.get(i)) {
                if(b.hitBy(ball)) {
                    player.setScore(player.getScore() + b.getBrickType().getPoints());
                    b.decrementType();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetBall() {
        if(gameOver()) {
            time.stop();
            return;
        }
        ball.setX(WIDTH/2);
        ball.setDY((HEIGHT/2) + 80);
        player.setLives(player.getLives() -1);
        player.setScore(player.getScore() <= 1);

    }

    private boolean gameOver() {
        if(player.getLives() <= 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        bufferedGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        player.drawPaddle(bufferedGraphics);
        player.drawBall(bufferedGraphics);
        for(ArrayList<Bricks> row : bricks) {
        for(Bricks b : row) {
            b.drawBrick(bufferedGraphics);
        }
        }

        bufferedGraphics.setFont(scoreFont);
        bufferedGraphics.drawString("Score: " + player.getScore(), 10, 25);
        if(gameOver() && ball.getY() >= HEIGHT) {
            bufferedGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
            bufferedGraphics.setFont(endFont);
            bufferedGraphics.drawString("Game Over Score: " + player.getScore(), (WIDTH /2) -85, (HEIGHT/2));

        }
        if(empty()) {
            bufferedGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
            bufferedGraphics.setFont(endFont);
            bufferedGraphics.drawString("You won. Score: " + player.getScore(), (WIDTH /2) -85, (HEIGHT /2));
            time.stop();
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private boolean empty() {
        for(ArrayList<Bricks> al : bricks) {
            if(al.size() != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        player.setX(e.getX() - (Paddle.PADDLE_WIDTH / 2));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(time.isRunning()) {
            return;
        }
        time.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}  
}
```

Comment: 1) Please don't leave so much space between lines. This makes the program harder to read, extra spacing between lines should be used only to create blocks of code. 2) Don't use `Canvas` it's an AWT component and thus deprecated. Use a `JPanel` instead (unless `Canvas` is a custom class of yours and we require it) 3) *"My JFrame is just blank and i don't know how to fix it?"* What do you expect to appear? You're just adding a blank canvas to your `JFrame`. 4) For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] (preferably with the imports)

Comment: i couldn't add the questios without the lines in code. I don't know why tho. Canvas is my class there i write code for the game, I have the size, color, Place etc for the bricks in my brick class, Everything to draw the ball in the ball class and Everything to draw the paddle in the paddle class

Comment: Remove `setResizable(false)` and resize your `JFrame` and have a look if something appears. Maybe something is wrong with `pack()`.
Could you please show your class `Canvas`.

Comment: I added it as an answer, cuz it was too long for a comment. Do you want to see the code for drawing, ball, paddle and bricks too?

Comment: @Natalia don't put it in a comment, [edit] your question instead and delete the answer. Answers are not for details.

Comment: I already edited the code for you, but next time, don't post edits as answers. Did you read the link about the [mcve] I posted? I bet you didn't. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you still don't understand how to create a MCVE read about the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) and if still don't, ask what part you don't understand. We should be able to copy-paste-run your code without modification and see the same result as you, but we **don't** want your whole code, we want a short example that still reproduces your issue.

Comment: Your code isn't **Minimal** nor it's **Complete**, we don't have access to the `Bricks` class, nor `Paddle` or `Ball`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Preparing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as required in SO, not only it makes helping much easier. 
In many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem, so it is a good debugging tool.
To answer "why is my JFrame blank ?" you could create the minimal code example like the following (copy-paste the entire code into `GameBoard.java` and run):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

        static final int HEIGHT = 600, WIDTH = 720, BRICK_ROWS = 8;
        private final int horizontalCount;
        private static final Font scoreFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 15);
        private final Paddle player;
        private final Ball ball;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Brick>> bricks;

    public GameBoard() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        player = new Paddle(WIDTH/2-Paddle.PADDLE_WIDTH/2);
        ball = new Ball (player.getX() + Paddle.PADDLE_WIDTH / 2 - Ball.DIAMETER / 2,
                                                        Paddle.Y_POS - (Ball.DIAMETER + 10 ));
        bricks = new ArrayList<>();
        horizontalCount = WIDTH / Brick.BRICK_WIDTH;
        for(int i = 0; i < BRICK_ROWS; ++i) {

            ArrayList<Brick> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j = 0; j < horizontalCount; ++j) {
                Brick tempBrick = new Brick(j*Brick.BRICK_WIDTH , Brick.BRICK_YPOS + i*Brick.BRICK_HEIGHT);
                temp.add(tempBrick);
            }
            bricks.add(temp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2D.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        player.drawPaddle(g2D);
        ball.drawBall(g2D);
        for(ArrayList<Brick> row : bricks) {
            for(Brick b : row) {
                b.drawBrick(g2D);
            }
        }
        g2D.setFont(scoreFont);
        g2D.drawString("Score: " + player.getScore(), 10, 25);
    }
}

class Paddle{

    public final static int PADDLE_WIDTH = 100, PADDLE_HEIGHT= 30, Y_POS = GameBoard.HEIGHT - 2* PADDLE_HEIGHT;
    private int xPos, score;

    Paddle(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }

    void setX(int xPos) {this.xPos = xPos;}

    int getX() {return xPos;}

    String getScore() {
        return String.valueOf(score);
    }

    void drawPaddle(Graphics2D g2D) {
        g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2D.fillRect(xPos, Y_POS, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(400,250);
        frame.add(new GameBoard());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Brick{

    final static int BRICK_WIDTH = 80, BRICK_HEIGHT = 15, BRICK_YPOS = 50;
    int xPos, yPos;

    Brick(int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    void drawBrick(Graphics2D g2D) {
        g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2D.fillRect(xPos, yPos, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2D.drawRect(xPos, yPos, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
    }
}

class Ball{

    final static int DIAMETER = 40;
    int xPos, yPos;

    Ball(int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    void drawBall(Graphics2D g2D) {
        g2D.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2D.fillOval(xPos, yPos, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }
}
```

This produces the following result, which I believe can serve as the basis of what you wanted to achieve:

[image]

Now start adding the missing functionality and see what breaks it.

Comment: To OP: I would suggest changing the `Canvas` class in order to not get confused with the `java.awt.Canvas` class maybe to `GameCanvas`